# Whenever I upload video the page getting hang

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7

I am doing a chatting app with JSQmessagecontroller library every thing is working fine but whenever I upload video the page get hang.

I am doing a chatting app with JSQmessagecontroller library every thing is working fine but whenever I upload video the page get hang.

```
  - (id<JSQMessageData>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {


        NSString * chat = [[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Message"];
        NSString * imageurl = [[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"media"];


        if (chat == nil)
        {


             //  NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:webdata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                           if ([imageurl rangeOfString:@".jpg"].location == NSNotFound) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{





                                        NSLog(@"Video is Loading....");

                                        image1 =[[UIImageView alloc]init];

                    MPMoviePlayerController *player1 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl]];


                    [player1 stop];

                    [self thumbnailImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl]];
                    JSQPhotoMediaItem *vitem;
                    vitem = [[JSQPhotoMediaItem alloc] initWithImage:thumbnailImage];

                    // NSString * date12=[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];



                    NSString *dateString = [[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];
                    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

                    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YY HH:mm a"];
                    dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
                    dateFromString=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];


                    messageForRow = [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"UserId"] senderDisplayName:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"]date:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"]   media:vitem] ;

                //   JSQPhotoMediaItem *vitem = [[JSQPhotoMediaItem alloc] initWithImage:thumbnailImage];


                                 });
                             });
                }

                else

                {

                    image1 =[[UIImageView alloc]init];

                    UIImage *im=[[UIImage alloc]init];

                    [image1 sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl]
                                               placeholderImage:nil];
                    im=image1.image;

                    JSQPhotoMediaItem *item = [[JSQPhotoMediaItem alloc] initWithImage:im];

                    NSString *dateString = [[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];
                    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

                    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YY HH:mm a"];
                    //dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
                    dateFromString=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];



                    messageForRow = [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"UserId"] senderDisplayName:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] date:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"] media:item] ;
                }

        }

        else
        {


             messageForRow = [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"UserId"] senderDisplayName:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] date:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"] text: [[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Message"]] ;

        }



        return messageForRow;

    }
```

Comment: I think it is because you are doing most of the work on main thread `dispatch_get_main_queue()`.

Comment: I have added asyn thread also you can see     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

Comment: Do long running task in Background and update UI in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ `  to avoid blocking of UI.

Comment: I have implemented the code still it is hang.

Comment: The `dispatch_async` will not wait for the call to return but you are still using main queue so the main queue will be blocked while it is executing your code. So any long running task should be done on another queue and the result should be pushed to UI thread if required.

Comment: Hi I am not able to understand could you give example where I need to change.

Comment: Please check my project and help me on this.,,,:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rwqjmxqusxi91z0/ChatAppodz.zip?dl=0